# Double API data on the same table

Tags: javascript, api

do I have a question?

Can we connect two APIs on the same JavaScript page and retrieve the data from both APIs in the same table?

I want to connect two APIs and display the results of both APIs in the same table. The API is the same, only the Token changes.

Here is the code in JS

```
function csvJSON(csv) {
    const lines = csv.split('\n');
    const result = [];
    const headers = lines[0].split(',');
 
    for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
      if (!lines[i]) continue;
      const obj = {};
      const currentline = lines[i].split(',');
 
      for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
      }
      result.push(obj);
    }
    return result;
  }

function boutonSubmit(){

bounceType = document.getElementById('BouncesType').value;
datestart = document.getElementById('dateS').value;
dateend = document.getElementById('dateE').value;
//bounceCode = getElementById('#dateS').value;   

// TOTAL BOUNCES

// Récupération des donnèes et convertion     
        fetch(`https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=867xxxxxxxGN&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`)
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((txtResponse) => {
            const data = csvJSON(txtResponse);

            const tbody = document.querySelector('#user-table tbody');
            
            tbody.innerHTML = '';

            

        data.forEach( (user) => {
            const entry = document.createElement('tr')
       
        entry.innerHTML = `

            <tr>
                <td class="column1">${user.Date}</td>
                <td class="column2">${user.Email}</td>
                <td class="column3">${user.BounceCode}</td>
                <td class="column3">${user["BounceType "]}</td>
            </tr>
            `;
          
            tbody.appendChild(entry);
                });
            })}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _“do I have a question?”_ - currently, you do not appear to have one that is actually a good fit for this site; or probably you don’t know how to actually ask it yet. So please go read [ask] first of all.

Comment: yes, there is no limit to the number of API calls you can make.

Comment: Yes, we can. Please include some code with the attempt you made or be more specific about your problem. You can either edit this question or post a new one! As it is, your question will soon be deleted because too vague. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Can you post some more details? from the looks of it, you can make 2 separate API calls, and as you receive the responses, you can update the table with the data. You can perform some processing to append data from both API calls together. I assume there would be some logic there on how to merge data from both APIs.

Comment: I add some details